# Условие IN в запросе к Dynamo DB

Tags: java, amazon

Здравствуйте, как сделать вместо `Id = :first OR Id = :second` условие с использование `IN` ?

```
public List<Data> getByIds(List<Long> ids) {
    Table table = dynamoDB.getTable(getTableName());
    ScanSpec scanSpec = new ScanSpec()
            .withFilterExpression("Id = :first OR Id = :second")
            .withValueMap(new ValueMap()
                    .withNumber(":first", ids.get(0))
                    .withNumber(":second", ids.get(1))
            );
    ItemCollection<ScanOutcome> scanOutcome = table.scan(scanSpec);
    return convertItemToData(scanOutcome.iterator());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можно сделать так

```
{
    //...
    Condition condition = new Condition()
            .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.IN.toString())
            .withAttributeValueList(buildAttributeValueList(userId));

    ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest()
            .withTableName(getTableName())
            .withScanFilter(ImmutableMap.of("userId", condition));

    ScanResult scanResult = amazonDynamoDBClient.scan(scanRequest);
```

Comment: Как сделать обект с `scanResult`?